# Как отобразить экран приветствия (splash screen) с именами разработчиков и логотипом компании?

Tags: c++, qt

Такая задача: нужно чтобы при запуске программы отображалась картина(обложка). Как пример привожу netbeans:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в моем случае, нужно чтоб просто отображалась обложка с именами разработчиков и логотипом компании.

Есть одна идея: программа при запуске просто открывает эту картину, но думаю это слишком просто(не надежно). Хотелось бы узнать есть ли способ получше?

Среда разработки: Qt C++.

Comment: Открытие и показ картинки это очень надежно - надо только правильно указать к ней путь ) Рекомендую изучить класс `QSplashScreen`. Если что, его можно наследовать, прочесть список разрабов из какого-нибудь тайного места и нарисовать поверх картинки.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть для этого готовый класс `QSplashScreen`.
Читайте хэлп в `Qt`.
Пример оттуда:

```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);
      QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");
      QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
      splash.show();
      app.processEvents();
      ...
      QMainWindow window;
      window.show();
      splash.finish(&window);
      return app.exec();
  }
```